# MySQL Case Statement - Unknown column in where

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a problem with my query, what's wrong?

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 300 THEN 2 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 300 THEN 3 
    END as id_ranking
FROM cp_pessoa 
    WHERE id_ranking IN (1,2);
```

I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'id_ranking' in 'where clause'

Thank you!

Comment: Where doesnt see aliases.

Answer (score 6):

It's because SELECT prepares result (as id_ranking) AFTER the WHERE is called.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
    WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 300 THEN 2 
    WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 300 THEN 3 
END as id_ranking
FROM cp_pessoa 
WHERE cp_pessoa.score < 300;
```

This is how that works (order):

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

Comment: Don't have other method to resolve? The piece "id_ranking(1,2)" is variable

Comment: It's a good standard method, but you can have one result with many other methods. You can dublicate your CASE in WHERE clause, for example, or select into another table and than use your current clause (2 querys). But are you really need this?

Answer (score 5):

Aliases are not allowed in `where`. Change query to either

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 300 THEN 2 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 300 THEN 3 
    END as id_ranking
FROM cp_pessoa 
)a 
WHERE id_ranking IN (1,2)
```

or

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 300 THEN 2 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 300 THEN 3 
    END as id_ranking
FROM cp_pessoa 
WHERE 
  CASE 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 300 THEN 2 
        WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 300 THEN 3 
    END IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Yor WHERE works everywhere, because of 1,2 and 3 always < 300

Comment: @BaBL86: true, fixing

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias in the where clause, instead try

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 100 THEN 1 
    WHEN cp_pessoa.score < 300 THEN 2 
    WHEN cp_pessoa.score >= 300 THEN 3 
END as id_ranking
FROM cp_pessoa 
WHERE cp_pessoa.score < 300
```